# MD5/SHA Ubuntu Download verification

Tags: command-line, 20.04, shortcut-keys, terminator, helpfile

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to download and verify the MD5,SHA file on the terminal.

Comment: See the complete tutorial on verifying the Ubuntu .iso file at https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

In ubunt, These are part of the coreutils and gnupg packages, which are installed by default.
you can check their version by typing this in terminal

```
md5sum --version
sha256sum --version
```

to verify your downloaded file in ubuntu, you can type
example

```
sha256sum filename.extension
```

eg,

```
sha256sum ubuntu-9.10-dvd-i386.iso
```

it should return something like this

```
c01b39c7a35ccc3b081a3e83d2c71fa9a767ebfeb45c69f08e17dfe3ef375a7b
```

or for md5hash
eg,

```
$ md5sum groups.csv or $ md5sum filename.extension
```

it should return something like
*bc527343c7ffc103111f3a694b004e2f*

Comment: Could you please let me know where I can check the name.extension of my files if there is a difference from the command that you provide me with.

Comment: the file extension is simply a file type. eg. if you have a file named ubuntu-9.10-dvd-i386.iso the extension would be .iso .